# What type of creature makes those mounds?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Location: South Ireland,
Appeared: 2020
Nearest river: 500 meter down hill south
Water is running down the hill also but there’s drainage to not flood the grass
Seen before: potted plant

I  used earth like this from a different location to plant a potted plant into a plant pot and those type of mounds happened afterwards in there also. Just on a smaller scale.

Never seen anything move though. Probably night active.

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three]
[image: four]
[image: five]

Comment: What size are the mounds? How close are you to a body of water (river, lake, etc)?

Comment: Added measurements and water proximity

Comment: do you know what worm mounds are like? if it's in a lawn then it's probably a worm cast, worms dig by passing soil through them and travel to the surface to place blobs there like black spagettis, when it rains they can lose their spagetti shape, so you only have 20% of your ones, the most recent that are still spagetti shaped.